# In jenkins not able to connect to slave

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

In master- slave the after running the jar for the slave  from command prompt it is displaying connected but in the Jenkins it is displaying not getting connected  to the slave The jenkins is deployed on linux server and trying to connect to slave from windows server by running slave jar

Comment: My crystal ball is in under maintenance. Look at the node's console to see what error messages it shows and paste them into your question.

Comment: Please provide more details. Describe your setup in as much detail as possible. What is the OS of your server and your slave? What type of slave? How exactly do you start the slave? Full printout of the slave command? The more details you can provide, the better help you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > See listed nodes and click on the slave name. You should be able to Launch agent from browser on slave.
If an error occurs, paste the error message here.

Comment: Below is the error i am getting 4:40:13,161 WARNING [hudson.node_monitors.ResponseTimeMonitor] (Response Time) Making Pravin System offline because it’s not responding
04:40:13,164 WARNING [hudson.node_monitors.ResponseTimeMonitor] (Response Time) Making RajuNode offline because it’s not responding